# Efficient way to renumber source and target using pgRouting

Tags: pgrouting, routing

pgRouting is a powerful tool for users to handle routing tasks, and I am now use pgRouting 2.1 to route a river (line shapefile).

Before starting to route, the first thing to do is always to create a routable table, and I use `pgr_createTopology` to create source and target of any edge.

Here is the problem, if I want every direction of 'from-source-to-target' in all edges to be the same, I need to check and renumber them manually.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

P.S. I have seen the following posts, and still have no idea to solve this problem.
[PGR_CREATETOPOLOGY](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/functions/create_topology.html)

[How does assign_vertex_id() in pgRouting work?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/how-does-assign-vertex-id-in-pgrouting-work/14347#14347)

[pgRouting assign number of source and target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887283/pgrouting-assign-number-of-source-and-target)